# Should I use one firebase-query and programmatically change the query parameters or is it ok to use multiple firebase-query elements in the same file?

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire, polymer-elements

I have multiple queries in the same polymer element that are from different location in Firebase. I am wondering if that's ok to use one firebase-query element and change the path programmatically and if yes how? I have come across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Jv6qGdV_URQ) and [this](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/21) which seem to show some issues.

And is there a problem with using multiple firebase-query elements in the same custom element of mine? 
I'm mostly looking for best practices here if there's any. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I think the way is to find a middle ground here. I try to have one firebase-query by data I need at the same time. The only drawback of having severals firebase-query in the same element is the number of simultaneous requests. If it begin to be slow, I try to refactor my app to reduce the amount of data needed at the same time.

Comment: @Arfost, Thanks for the comment, you are right.